# Which is the incorrect Variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program is supposed to display the total occupancy rate and individual floor occupancy of a hotel. The total amount of rooms occupied does not accumulate with each iteration. I've attempted to dissect the issue but to no avail. I have a feeling the problem is obvious.

```
#Welcome message and hotel info
print("WELCOME TO THE GRAND NEW HOTEL!!!")
print("-----------------------------------")

print("Total number of floors in the hotel : 8")
print("Total number of rooms in each floor : 30")
print("Total Number of rooms in the hotel :240\n")

print("-----------------------------------\n")

#Variable for Hotel 
total_in_floor = 30
total_in_hotel = 240
rented_in_floor = 0
rented_in_hotel = 0
rate_of_floor = 0
rate_of_hotel = 0

#User Input
for i in range(8):
   while True:
      try:
      #loop until the nimber is correct
         print("Please enter rented rooms in Floor No. {0}".format(i+1))
         rented_in_floor = int(input())
         if 0 <= rented_in_floor <= 30:
            break
      except ValueError:
            #int() will not go past until input is a valid number
            print("Retry")






rate_of_floor = int((rented_in_floor))/int((total_in_floor))*100

print("Occupancy rate of Floor No.{0} is = {1}%\n".format(i+1,round(rate_of_floor,2)))

rented_in_hotel = int(rented_in_hotel) + int(rented_in_floor)

rate_of_hotel = int((rented_in_hotel))/int((total_in_hotel))*100

print("Total rooms rented in entire hotel : {0}\n".format(rented_in_hotel))

print("Occupancy rate of the hotel is = {0} % \n".format(round(rate_of_hotel,2))
```

Comment: you don't use `+` so how it should cumulate values ?

Comment: print("Occupancy rate of the hotel is = {0} % \n".format(round(rate_of_hotel,2))
A closing bracket is missing in this line

Answer (score 0):

```
#Welcome message and hotel info
print("WELCOME TO THE GRAND NEW HOTEL!!!")
print("-----------------------------------")

print("Total number of floors in the hotel : 8")
print("Total number of rooms in each floor : 30")
print("Total Number of rooms in the hotel :240\n")

print("-----------------------------------\n")

#Variable for Hotel
total_in_floor = 30
total_in_hotel = 240
rented_in_floor = 0
rented_in_hotel = 0
rate_of_floor = 0
rate_of_hotel = 0

#User Input
for i in range(8):
   while True:
      try:
      #loop until the nimber is correct
         print("Please enter rented rooms in Floor No. {}".format(i+1))
         rented_in_floor = int(input())
         if 0 <= rented_in_floor <= 30:
             rate_of_floor = int((rented_in_floor)) / int((total_in_floor)) * 100
             print("Occupancy rate of Floor No.{0} is = {1}%\n".format(i + 1, round(rate_of_floor, 2)))
             break
      except ValueError:
            #int() will not go past until input is a valid number
            print("Retry")

   rented_in_hotel = int(rented_in_hotel) + int(rented_in_floor)

rate_of_hotel = int((rented_in_hotel))/int((total_in_hotel))*100

print("Total rooms rented in entire hotel : {0}\n".format(rented_in_hotel))

print("Occupancy rate of the hotel is = {0} % \n".format(round(rate_of_hotel,2)))
```

Try this code.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you need, I think this modified code may help you.
I have added some comments in the parts I've modified or added.

```
print("WELCOME TO THE GRAND NEW HOTEL!!!")
print("-----------------------------------")

print("Total number of floors in the hotel : 8")
print("Total number of rooms in each floor : 30")
print("Total Number of rooms in the hotel :240\n")

print("-----------------------------------\n")


total_in_floor = 30
total_in_hotel = 240
rented_in_floor = 0
rented_in_hotel = 0
# rate_of_floor = 0  #not necessary at this point
rate_of_hotel = 0

list_of_floors = [] # create a list where storing "rented_in_floor" for each floor

for i in range(8):
    while True:
        try:
            print("Please enter rented rooms in Floor No. {0}".format(i+1))
            rented_in_floor = int(input())
            if 0 <= rented_in_floor <= 30:
                list_of_floors.append(rented_in_floor) # add the number of rented rooms in the "i+1"th floor to the list
                rented_in_hotel += rented_in_floor # accumulate the total amount of rooms occupied in the hotel
                break

            else:  # in the case the input number is larger than 30, explain what is the problem
                print("Please enter a number of rented room not larger than 30")

        except ValueError:
            print("Retry")





for i in range(8):  # print all the floors' occupancy rates
    rented_in_floor_temp = list_of_floors[i] # select the number of rented room in the floor of index i inside "list_of_floors" (basically, the "i+1"th floor of the hotel)
    rate_of_floor = int((rented_in_floor_temp))/int((total_in_floor))*100  # same as before, but with "rented_in_floor_temp"

    print("Occupancy rate of Floor No.{0} is = {1}%\n".format(i+1,round(rate_of_floor,2)))

# rented_in_hotel = int(rented_in_hotel) + int(rented_in_floor)  # delete, "rented_in_hotel" has been defined above already

rate_of_hotel = int((rented_in_hotel))/int((total_in_hotel))*100

print("Total rooms rented in entire hotel : {0}\n".format(rented_in_hotel))

print("Occupancy rate of the hotel is = {0} % \n".format(round(rate_of_hotel,2)))
```